Comparison Principle for 2 heat equations
I'm having trouble showing the following:
Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded with $C^1$-boundary $\partial U$. Assume that $u_1,u_2\in C^{1,2}(U_T)\cap C\overline{(U_T)}$ are solutions of the initial-boundary value problems
$$(u_i)_t(x,t)-\Delta u_i(x,t)=f_i(x,t,u_i(x,t)),$$
$$u_i(x,t)=g_i(x,t),$$
where $f_i\in C(U_T\times\mathbb{R})$ and $g_i\in C(\Gamma_T),i=1,2$. Show that if
$$f_1(x,t,u_1)\leq f_2(x,t,u_2)\qquad \text{in }U_T\times \mathbb{R},$$
$$g_1(x,t)\leq g_2(x,t)\qquad \text{on }\Gamma_T,$$
then, the solutions satisfy $u_1\leq u_2$ on $U_T$.
Where $U_T:=U\times (0,T]$, and $\Gamma_T:=\overline{U_T}- U=(\partial U\times [0,T])\cup(U\times\{0\})$.
I tried to show this by using a function $v(x,t)=(u_2-u_1)(x,t)$, but I got stuck doing this. A solution would be appreciated! (I'm selfstudying PDE using Evans' book and Lecture Notes published by my University, which is where this problem is taken from)
EDIT: What I've tried so far:
Let $v(x,t):=(u_2-u_1)(x,t)$, then $$w(x,0)=u_2(x,0)-u_1(x,0)=g_2(x,t)-g_1(x,t)\geq0.$$
We next want to show that $v$ solves the following boundary-value problem:
$$v(x,t)_t-\Delta v(x,t)=f(x,t,v(x,t))\qquad\text{in }U_T\times\mathbb{R},$$
$$v(x,t)=g(x,t)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\text{on }\Gamma_T.$$
Now $$v(x,t)_t=(u_2(x,t)-u_1(x,t))_t=(u_2(x,t))_t-(u_1(x,t))_t,$$ and
$$\Delta v(x,t)=\Delta (u_2(x,t)-u_1(x,t))=\Delta u_2(x,t)-\Delta u_1(x,t),$$ we get $$v(x,t)_t-\Delta v(x,t)=(u_2(x,t))_t-(u_1(x,t))_t+\Delta u_2(x,t)-\Delta u_1(x,t)$$ $$=(u_2(x,t))_t+\Delta u_2(x,t)-((u_1(x,t))_t+\Delta u_1(x,t))=f_2(x,t,u_2(x,t))-f_1(x,t,u_1(x,t)).$$
Next we do the same on the boundary,$$v(x,0)=u_2(x,0)-u_1(x,0)=g_2(x,t)-g_1(x,t).$$
Now we can take $$f(x,t,v(x,t))=f_2(x,t,u_2(x,t))-f_1(x,t,u_1(x,t)),$$ and $$g(x,t)=g_2(x,t)-g_1(x,t),$$ and apply Theorem 4 in 2.3.3. of Evans' book and see that the minimum of $v$ is the same on $\overline{U_T}$ as on $\Gamma_T$, and thus the minimum of $v(x,t)$ is equal to the minimum on $v(x,0)$, now since we know $v(x,0)\geq0$, we know that the minimum of $v(x,t)\geq0$ and thus $v(x,t)\geq0$ everywhere on $U_T$, thus $u_2(x,t)\geq u_1(x,t)$ on $U_T$ as desired.
Now I'm not sure if we can say $f(x,t,v(x,t))=f_2(x,t,u_2(x,t))-f_1(x,t,u_1(x,t)),$ and $g(x,t)=g_2(x,t)-g_1(x,t)$.

We're not familiar with the parabolic function and the $Lu$ term used in the Theorem you mentioned. I think I did find what I need to do, if I can prove that $v$ is a solution, then the same result holds with Theorem 4 in 2.3.3. of Evans' book. Would that work too?

@Tulip I added my attempt just now! Would appreciate it if you could take a look.

Thank you a lot! All clear now!

After a year I've redone this problem some weeks ago and got a more elementary proof, so without the use of elliptic operators as described in the the comments (but more like my original approach, but with a more concise proof) on the question.
Let us consider $w=u_1-u_2$, then
\begin{align*}
    \partial_tw(x,t)-\Delta w(x,t)&=f(x,t,u_1(x,t))-f(x,t,u_2(x,t)),\qquad&(x,t)\in U_T,\\
    w(x,t)&=g_1(x,t)-g_2(x,t),&(x,t)\in\Gamma_T,
\end{align*}
and since $f(x,t,u_1(x,t))-f(x,t,u_2(x,t))\leq 0$ we can apply the maximum principle, and thus we know
$$\max_{(x,t)\in\overline{U_T}}w(x,t)=\max_{(x,t)\in\Gamma_T}(g_1(x,t)-g_2(x,t)),$$
but now since $g_1(x,t)\leq g_2(x,t)$, we get $\max_{(x,t)\in\Gamma_T}(g_1(x,t)-g_2(x,t))\leq 0$, and thus
$\max_{(x,t)\in\overline{U_T}}w(x,t)\leq0$, so in particular we have $w(x,t)\leq0$ in $U_T\subseteq \overline{U_T}$, so $u_1-u_2\leq 0$, or equivalently $u_1\leq u_2$ in $U_T$.
